# how to include standard SF javascript files in offline manifest

Tags: mobile, javascript-remoting, offline

My offline manifest is working correctly however when the internet connection is restored and it attempts to use javascript remoting to save updates I'm getting an error that the variable `Visualforce` was not found, referring to my JS remoting call `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction`.

I haven't included VFRemote.js or any standard SF javascript files in my offline manifest. What is the best way to include these? Is this type of path going to be consistent across different orgs? `/jslibrary/1400541830000/sfdc/VFRemote.js` ? Is there a way to include it with a merge field syntax?